# Connect to Grails Datasource from Grails Plugin Command

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm attempting to write a plugin for Grails that will automatically generate my domain classes based on special views that we're designing in our legacy database. I basically just want to save myself some time manually writing all the mapping stuff required to make the domain classes work.

Do I have access to the dataSource defined in the application.yml of the project from a custom ApplicationCommand implementation? If so, how do I pull it so I can open my connection to the database?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491074/grails-getting-the-data-source-in-a-normal-groovy-class). The dataSource bean that is injected into regular artefacts can be accessed through the `ApplicationContext` like this:

```
def dataSource = applicationContext.getBean('dataSource')
```